# Unable to Retrieve Data from useMutation Call Despite Successful Internal Fetch

Tags: next.js, react-query, trpc

I'm relatively new to tRPC so please bear with me on this.
I'm encountering an issue with the `useMutation` query. When I call `useMutation` with new input, it returns `undefined` for data. However, [I can see that the data is successfully retrieved internally](https://i.imgur.com/WjvQnQ1.png), as confirmed by tRPC's debugging console and an `onSuccess` call within the `useMutation` variable.

I'm struggling to understand how to properly rretrieve mutated data with tRPC, and I would appreciate some guidance on resolving this issue.

**Front-End**

```js
  // fetch data
  const dataMutation = api.post.queryByFilter.useMutation({
    onSuccess(data) {
      console.log("onSuccess: ", data);
    },
  });

  const fetchData = async () => {
    // set dates for query
    setMonthsBack(monthsBack + 1);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - monthsBack);
    const getMonth = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    const getYear = currentDate.getFullYear().toString();

    dataMutation.mutate({
      company: "google",
      month: getMonth.toString(),
      year: getYear,
    });

    console.log("Fetch Data: ", dataMutation.data);

    // append to cardSets; not relevant for this example
    setCardSets([
      ...cardSets,
      { data: dataMutation, month: getMonth.toString(), year: getYear },
    ]);
    // increment page; not relevant for this example
    setPage(page + 1);
  };
```

**Back-End**

```js
  queryByFilter: publicProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        company: z.string(),
        month: z.string(),
        year: z.string(),
      }),
    )
    .mutation(({ input, ctx }) => {
      const { company, month, year } = input;

      const startDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-01`);
      const endDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-31`);

      return ctx.db.spottings.findMany({
        where: {
          company: company,
          date: { gte: startDate, lte: endDate },
        },
        orderBy: { date: "desc" },
      });
    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataMutation.mutate` is any async operation. It calls your backend and successfully resolves the API call with data, but if you try to access the `.data` immediately, it's not there *yet*. That's why there is an `onSuccess` callback.

You can either use the `onSuccess` like so:

```
    dataMutation.mutate({
      company: "google",
      month: getMonth.toString(),
      year: getYear,
    }, {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log("Fetch Data: ", data);
        // put your code here
      }
    });
```

or you should be able to leverage `mutateAsync` API:

```
    const data = await dataMutation.mutateAsync({
      company: "google",
      month: getMonth.toString(),
      year: getYear,
    }
    console.log("Fetch Data: ", data);
    // put your code here
```

see official docs https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/mutations